# Best way to calculate city influence maps similar to civilisation?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

As the title says, imagine you want to generate the influence mask for a city, given that the map is a 2D grid rather than hex. An extra bit is that different points on the map might have different "influence absorpion" values. Some simple scenarios to make it less abstract: 

Scenario 1:
City centered at (5,2) has 10 influence
All tiles have influence_absorption = 1
Tile at (6,2) has 9 influence, therefore within the influence of the city
Tile at (7,2) has 8 influence, therefore within the influence of the city
Tile at (14,2) has 1 influence, therefore within the influence of the city
Tile at (15,2) has 0 influence, therefore out of the influence of the city

Scenario 2:
City centered at (5,2) has 10 influence
All tiles have influence_absorption = 1, but tile at (6,2) has influence_absorption=4
Tile at (6,2) has 9 influence, therefore within the influence of the city
Tile at (7,2) has 5 influence, therefore within the influence of the city
Tile at (11,2) has 1 influence, therefore within the influence of the city
Tile at (12,2) has 0 influence, therefore out of the influence of the city

It's like using dijkstra on a 2D grid with single-source, multiple-destinations. Any pointers for good/fast algorithms are appreciated. Also, if this problem has a well-known name, that'd be appreciated as well.

I made the following algorithm (independently like Jon's, thanks btw, it's the intuitive solution I guess):

```
p0 = CITY_COORDS
Initialize all influences with 0
set CITY_INFLUENCE as the new influence at p0
list = [ p0 ]
while list not empty
    p = get point in list with highest influence rating
    pi = get influence at point
    pa = get absorption at point
    new_i = pi -pa
    list_is_updated = false
    for each valid neighbour nb
        nbi = get neighbour's influence
        if new_i > nbi
            set new_i as the new influence at nb
            add nb to list
            list_is_updated = true
    if list_is_updated
        sort list // with selection sort, very fast
```

And I have the following results, which can also be helpful to understand what I'm after:

**Influence absorption**
[image]

**Influence mask**
[image: Influence mask]

**Influence visualisation (city at the brightest spot)**
[image: Influence visualisation]

Comment: In scenario 2, what's to stop the influence solver from going around (6,2), i.e. (5,2)->(5,3)->(6,3)->(7,3)->(7,2), and thus solve (7,2) as 6 influence instead?

Comment: @congusbongus: nothing would (unless (5,3) etc had similar absorption).

Comment: @Jon: not quite. Only city tiles emit influence, the rest just allow influence to propagate

Comment: Having never played *Civilisation*, this question is quite unclear to me. How does this "influence" thing work?

Comment: updated with some screens, hopefully clearer now

Comment: @Anko, each tile contains an indicator to track how much "influence" each player has "added" to the tile. Each turn, cities generate some small amount and push it outward. Civ tries to send it directly to the closest, best, un-owned, tile it can, but may settle on one that is dominated by another players influence. Everything works better in your own influence and much, much, worse in everyone else's. If you've added 10k to a tile, and, next turn, I reach 10,001, the tile "flips" and becomes mine and I can work and defend it; this can eventually cause entire cities to starve and/or flip.

Answer (score 1):

(A place to start that's easier than comments:)

1. Maintain a list of tiles that need calculating; the initial list contains only the city-tiles.
2. Each city-tile generates influence, X, and adds it to each of its' 8 nearest neighbors, also adding each neighbor to the list. (Does the city pass only 1/8 of its influence to each?) The city-tile then removes itself from the list.
3. While the list is not empty...
4. Tiles don't send or receive 0 influence; the tile received influence, so it must be "in".
5. The tile removes itself from the list and subtracts its' influence factor from the received amount.
6. If there is any remainder, the tile adds it to its' 3 nearest neighbor(s). (Does the tile share only 1/3 of its' influence with each?) The direction that tile's should emit is easily determined with the vector between the tile and the city.
7. Any neighbor that receives influence is added to the list.
8. Goto 3

Comment: @Babis, if a tile receives influence but fully absorbs it and has none left to transmit, should it be considered in or out? Your wording makes me think #4 may belong after #5 and need the "remainder" conditional.

Comment: it would be in.

Comment: @Babis, I updated the list; it's pretty much the same as what you created?

Comment: @Babis, I'm also curious to know if you are going to, ultimately, shove all of this into a compute shader?

Comment: Similar but not the same. E.g. I didn't divide the influence by the neighbours, but I might try to do that to see how that differs! Probably not gonna shove it to a compute shader, as it's not that massively parallel anyway so I don't think it's worth the maintenance.

Comment: @Babis, I was thinking that each receiving tile has 3 adjacent senders, so if each sender sent 1/3, the receiver would get 3/3 == 100%. ??

Comment: Yes, but you can't be sure that the ratio will always be 1/3! imagine a peninsula which only has 1 neighbour. Even if you count the available senders, I'm not sure this is the best behavior, at least in my case. Imagine A) a city in the middle of endless plains (minimal absorption per tile) B) a city in a valley, surrounded by mountains with a narrow long strip of plains. In B, the influence will travel very far towards the strip, which I don't think should be the case